# Encoding issue on production server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-8

I have develop a web application which store some data on SQL database in xml format(data is getting from third party API). This data contains some special characters(Greek characters). These characters are stored and shown correctly in my local environment(hosted in IIS). When I move the code to production these Greek characters are not stored correctly in SQL. Any reason for this issue ?

Comment: Pls share your query

Answer (score 0):

*try prefixing the string containing cyrillic characters with N for unicode.*

```
INSERT INTO table(columnname) VALUES(N'yourstring')
```

Comment: we are serializing the API response and store it directly on SQL as xml data. Data type xml